# Checking for Win in Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

Hello I'm 17 and trying to learn how to code. I am having trouble debugging this section of code and would appreciate some help.

```
bool checkifwin(char grid[3][3], char player)
{
    if (checkverticle(char grid[3][3], char player) 
        || checkhorizontal(char grid[3][3], char player)
        || checkdiagonal( grid[3][3], player) 
       return true;
    else
       return false;
};
```

It says expected primary-expression before char.

Comment: Might be a typo, but you're missing a closing bracket after your `if` statement.

Comment: Just cosmetic -- you misspelled vertical. Sorry, it bothers me :/

Comment: You don't need a semicolon after the close brace of a function or method declaration.  (Class declarations need them, however...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

checkverticle() is a call to a function not a declaration so you don't need the "char"s.

```
bool checkifwin(char grid[3][3], char player)
{
    if ( checkverticle(grid, player) || 
         checkhorizontal(grid, player) || 
         checkdiagonal( grid, player) return true;
    else return false;
};
```

Just some coding advice. In my opinion:

```
bool func()
{
    if (expr)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Is not great style. I'd suggest refactoring it to:

```
bool func()
{
    bool result = false; // This just makes it clear the expected default.
    // You could even go as far as
    // bool result = expr  or event return expr; - although I suggest sticking with a
    // variable in case you need to debug.
    result = expr; // e.g. result = checkVert() || checkHoriz() || checkDiag();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to give type name while calling a function.

```
if (checkverticle(char grid[3][3], char player) // Remove char here and in other cases
```

Regarding the error further you get -

```
checkverticle( grid[3][3] ... )
```

Here `grid[3][3]` gives you the character at that index. What you really want to pass is `grid` itself as others suggested. And ofcourse, be wary of the valid array indexes.

Comment: Oh ok i got rid of those type names but now it says invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char (*)[3]'

Comment: sorry i think it might have to do with the other code so ill post the functions this one calls

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass type declarations as parameters. Try this instead:

```
bool checkifwin(char grid[3][3], char player)
{
  return checkverticle(grid], player) || 
    checkhorizontal(grid, player) || 
    checkdiagonal(grid, player;

};
```